# menu items toggle and display on screen size reduction

Tags: menus

I am working with a child of Twenty Twelve. I made my own images to act as menu li backgrounds. When I reduce the screen width by moving my browser window in, the menu items seem to toggle automatically. I have never fiddled with any of the CSS or JS for this behavior. The resulting dropped-down list overlays the other menu items and makes them unreadable. Not to mention, I don't want the behavior in the first place.

Is there such thing as auto-toggling?

Comment: This is a little confusing, could you provide URL to live site exhibiting your issue? Also note that if it's generic enough CSS/JS thing it is better asked at Stack Overflow.

Comment: www.efficiencyofmovement.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely the default behavior for Twenty Twelve; responsive for small screens and thus stacking elements on the page, including the contents of your nav, `#site-navigation`.

Let's looks at the nav section in the default TT theme:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
  <h3 class="menu-toggle">Menu</h3>
    <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a>
    <div class="nav-menu">
       <ul class="nav-menu">

         <!-- More stuff below: li items, closing /ul, /div /nav tags-->
```

Basically, following a mobile first design philosophy, TT by default hides `ul.nav-menu` (display: none). Through the use of media queries it makes it visible for screens that have a minimum width of 600px. Through jQuery by clicking on `.menu-toggle` it adds an additional class of `.toggled-on` to `ul.nav-menu` to make it visible.

```
 // TT style.css lines 597 to 604
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
.main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
   display: none;
}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu.toggled-on,
.menu-toggle {
   display: inline-block;
}

// 1421
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    .main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
.main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
    border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In your childtheme, you have overridden the default `display: none` styles for `.nav-menu` so it's visible at all screen sizes.

For a simple fix I would try to do something like this:

```
// Basically adding a media query to float your menu li elements when small screen using TT's breakpoint for small screens of 600px 
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
   .main-navigation li {
      float: left
   }
   ul.children {
      //hide the secondary links from displaying
      display:none;
   }
}
```

Comment: tnog, This solved exactly what I was asking. Thank you. I added some functionality with a ':hover' pseudo element to the ul.children element. It brought back the functionality that I wanted but alas it still doesn't look right, for me at least.

Comment: You're welcome. Considering that mobile is becoming an overriding trend I'd consider, rather than fighting against the functionality of the default mobile menu, of just incorporating it into your existing design. Maybe use the same media queries to present your existing design for larger screens and the mobile menu for small displays? But, of course, it's your design and your UI philosophy.